# Can we change Event scheduler time interval dynamically at run time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

Can we change Event scheduler time interval dynamically at run time in MySQL.
EX: Event time interval is every 5 mins. can we change this directly to 2 mins with out Alter statement through Application.

Kindly help me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably run the `ALTER EVENT` statement from the application, can't you?

If not - it may be only a matter of privileges - the app's user  should have the `EVENT` privilege.

Afaik, `ALTER` is the only way to change the scheduling (and I don't think there is a need for any other way).

Comment: But we wanted to change the time interval of an event by reading the interval from Database using procedure with dynamic sql. But it is failing when we are doing that. we are getting error message like "This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet"

please help me on this.

Comment: @Phanindra - Well I don't think you can do that with prepared statement. The only thing that comes to mind is reading the interval from the DB with one query, and then building the ALTER query in the application and running it (using string concatenation rather than prepared statements). I am not sure that's best practice but it should work.